# error: illegal start of statement (no modifiers allowed here) private def hasNoDuplicates(line: Array[Int]) = .... in Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to validate a Soduko board. my input is of type Any, so first, I want to change that to Int. and validate that, I write the following code but it can not return the true result and return some error. how can I handle the problem of code? validate method comprised of two other method, one for convert Any to Int and another for validate Sudoko board.

```
def validate(lines: Array[Option[Any]]*): Boolean = {


object BoardParser {

  /**
    * Parse a Sudoku board from varargs
    * Board needs to have 9 rows, 9 columns & all Int or Long values for non-empty cells, to be accepted
    *
    * @param board Variable number of optional arrays
    * @return A 2D Int array representing the basic Sudoku board
    */
  def getValidBoard(board: Array[Option[Any]]*): Array[Array[Int]] = {
    def validateBoard() = {
      if (board.length != 9 || board.transpose.length != 9) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Board must be a 2D array of size 9x9")
      } else if (!board.forall(isAllNumbers)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Board must contain only Int or Long values")
      }
    }

    validateBoard()
    board.map(toNumbers).toArray
  }

  private def isAllNumbers(line: Array[Option[Any]]) = {
    line.forall {
      case Some(_: Int) => true
      case Some(_ : Long) => true
      case None => true
      case _ => false
    }
  }

  private def toNumbers(line: Array[Option[Any]]) = {
    line.map {
      case Some(x: Int) => x
      case Some(x: Long) => x.toInt
      case None => 0
      case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException
    }
  }

}
val valid_board = getValidBoard(lines)

def new_validate(board: Array[Array[Int]]): Boolean = {
  lazy val rowsValid = board.forall(hasNoDuplicates)
  lazy val columnsValid = board.transpose.forall(hasNoDuplicates)
  lazy val cellsValid = squaresHaveNoDuplicates(board)

  rowsValid && columnsValid && cellsValid
}

private def hasNoDuplicates(line: Array[Int]) = line.distinct.count(1 to 9             contains _) == line.count(_ != 0)

private def squaresHaveNoDuplicates(matrix: Array[Array[Int]]) = {
  val rowBlocks = matrix.grouped(3).toArray
  val transposed = rowBlocks.map(_.transpose)
  val squares = transposed.map(_.grouped(3).toArray)
  val squaresFlattened = squares.map(_.map(_.flatten))

  squaresFlattened.forall(_.forall(hasNoDuplicates))
}
return new_validate(valid_board)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring `hasNoDuplicates` inside a `def`. `private` is a valid modifier only within the immediate scope of an `object`, `class` or `trait`. Nested `def`s will anyway be visible exclusively within the scope of the outer `def` itself, so `private` wouldn't really make sense there. You can choose to either:

- remove the `private` modifier, or
- move `hasNoDuplicates` outside of `validate` (but remember it would only make sense for it to be `private` if it's in the immediate scope of an `object`, `class` or `trait`)

The first is easier but in general I would recommend maybe considering if you could resort less to nesting `def`s. Of course, that's for you to judge.

Comment: THANKS. I used the first idea. but now I get a new error. as you can see in my code the input of validate is the line: Array[Option[Any]]. but when I want send this value as a parameter to getValidBoard, the error is raised that said  found: Seq[Array[Option[Any]]]
 required: Array[Option[Any]]